# Netflix app on Smart TV with android

Tags: smart-tv, netflix

I just bought a cheap Polaroid smart Tv that comes with Android OS.
The specs are the following:

- OS: SmartTV OS
- CPU: Cortex-A53 4Core(64 bit) 1.5GHz (DVFS)
- GPU: Mali450MP 5 Core 750Mhz(DVFS)
- Android version: android 7.1.2
- ROM version: CV950XH_C42_SmartTV-V20190620

The Netflix app that comes with it is very old, Is there a website I can download a compatible Netflix .APK that I can install onto this Smart TV?

Comment: I assume there it is running on Android TV but doesn't have Play Store installed? Because otherwise, the Play Store will install the latest & most compatible APK for your system. On the other hand, [APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/netflix-inc/netflix-android-tv/) lists the existing APK for "Netflix (Android TV)". You can try to download and install it, and see if it works or not...

Comment: Tried this but I cannot install these packages.